# DateTime - 1 semana

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente variable:

```
  DateTime zonaSemana = DateTime.Today.AddDays(((int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek) == 0 ? 7 : ((int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7).AddSeconds(1);
```

Hay alguna forma de hacerla más corta? Se trata de que me la fecha del miercoles siguiente.

Es decir tengo las siguientes:

Esta añade 10 min:

```
 zonaMins = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
```

Esta 24 horas:

```
   zonaDias = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day, 0, 0, 1);
```

Pero la de 1 semana no me funciona bien y no sé el motivo. Me tiene que dar el miércoles y no sé si es por que es muy larga.. o algo.

gracias

Comment: ¿Y qué día te da?

Comment: me da siempre el miércoles siguiente. Que es la idea que cada miécoles a las 00:01 salte el programa.

Comment: A ver, no está muy claro. Dices en la pregunta _Se trata de que me la fecha del miercoles siguiente._ y ahora dices que _me da siempre el miércoles siguiente_. Puedes aclararlo un poco mas?

Comment: Es decir lo que necesito es que la variable que he puesto DateTime zonaSemana sea igual pero o más corto o parecido ya que está no me da el resultado que necesito por que el programa se me bloquea.

Yo necesito que cuando llegue el miercoles a las 00:01 se active un programa. Los otros dos que he puesto de ejmplo me funcionan perfectamente pero el de 1 vez a la semana no. ( 1 vez a la semana y concreta mente el miércoles )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bien, el problema es que si ejecutas el código el mismo día de la semana que estas buscando, no te da el miércoles siguiente sino el miércoles en el que ya estás. Eso se soluciona fácilmente buscando el siguiente martes, en lugar de el miércoles, y sumándole un día. O sea:

```
DateTime zonaSemana = DateTime.Today.AddDays((((int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7)+1 ).AddSeconds(1) ;
```

Comment: pruebo y te digo! :)

Answer (score 6):

Lo que puedes hacer es:

```
private DateTime calcularProxMiercoles()
{
    var day = DateTime.Today;
    do
    {
        day = day.AddDays(1);
    } while (day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
    return day;
}
```

Esto te retornará siempre el próximo miércoles(si hoy es miercoles y quieres que te retorne el mismo dia cambia el `do while` por solo el `while`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo puebo y te digo!

Comment: no hace falta que lo modifiques ya que actúa con la fecha actual, Me referia que si solo pones el while tambien obtendrás el resultado si HOY es miércoles, de la manera que lo publique obtendrás siempre el próximo, nunca el actual.

Comment: sii he borrado mi comentario, me he dado cuenta. Gracias!

Comment: A veces lo mas sencillo es lo óptimo, buena aportación!
Recomiendo @MontseMkd que si esta respuesta te ha solucionado el problema, la marques como respuesta correcta. Ya que con ello fomentas las respuestas de calidad como esta. Un saludo

Comment: @rencinas bueno, no se si un bucle es más óptimo que un cálculo mátematico, yo no estaría muy de acuerdo, pero desde luego esta respuesta es totalmente correcta y válida :)

Comment: @Pikoh es un bucle de como máximo 7 interacciones(en el caso del do while), considero que es una carga no demasiado elevada. Pero tan bien me refería a que es bastante mas sencillo de entender que una linea interminable con 4 o 5 paréntesis. Más que óptimo debería haber utilizado otra palabra. ;)

Comment: @rencinas por supuesto, te entiendo perfectamente. Obviamente con tan pocas interacciones el rendimiento no es relevante, mi único comentario era con lo de "óptimo". En cuanto a lo de mas fácil de entender, es posible que así sea. De todas maneras, como digo, es una respuesta tan válida o más que la mía, no tengo ninguna crítica :)